# Is 'co-conspirator' redundant?

Tags: redundancy

I've noticed in the news that multiple individuals involved in a crime are referred to as co-conspirators.

Etymonline gives the origin of [conspire](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=conspire&allowed_in_frame=0):

> **conspire** (v.): late 14c.,
>   from Old French conspirer (14c.), from Latin *conspirare* "to agree,
>   unite, plot," literally "to breathe together," from *com*- "together"
>   (see com-) + *spirare* "to breathe" (see spirit (n.)). Or perhaps the
>   notion is "to blow together" musical instruments, i.e., "To sound in
>   unison." Related: Conspired; conspiring.

Given that the *con* portion of the word means with or together, is the *co* redundant?

Comment: Also, if they're conspiring to steal hot chocolate, are they co-co-conspirators?

Comment: It's a redundant, invented word circa Watergate.  I rate it about as highly as I rate "commentator" (which should just be "commenter").  Somewhere along the line people decided they sounded more erudite if they used longer words, leading to a panoply of added prefixes and suffixes.

Comment: @Carl: No disrespect, but that's a redundant comment (and I use the word advisedly, whereas it seems you didn't! :) An hour before you posted it, I had posted an NGram showing that when associated with a possessive pronoun, the usage was already on a par with *conspirator* back in WW2. As for "coined circa Watergate", OED has its first citation dated 1863.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks for the data.  I'm not afraid of being corrected :-) .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft _Commentator_ has been in common use (much more common than _commenter_) since the 15th century. The _commenter/commentator_ pair reflects a similar pair in Latin _commentor_ (from the verb _comminiscī_) and _commentātor_ (from the verb _commentārī_, frequentative of _comminiscī_).

Comment: I put co-conspirator & irregardless in the same catagory.

Comment: Let me get this straight, the contention here is that one person can't conspire by himself, but it necessarily includes at least one other involved in a conspiracy, therefore a conspirator is already part of a group of at least two conspirators, and co-conspirator is tautologous?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft For me commenter and commentator have slight shades of distinction. I see a commenter as people writing in this comments section, and see commentators as sports commentators or political commentators. I like different words for different meanings.

Comment: @Zebrafish per Janus B J comment above, I defer to his insight.  Meanwhile, When it comes to  French Fries, I prefer using specialty potatos rather than a commentater.   :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usage of *conspirator / co-conspirator* has changed significantly over the past century or so...

[image]

But this applies only when it means *others involved in the same conspiracy as an identified subject explicitly referenced*. In all other contexts we still overwhelmingly use the "non-redundant" form...

[image]

---

Taking that distinction into account, I don't think *co-conspirators* is normally a "redundant" form. If I came across *your conspirators* today, I'd assume the person being addressed wasn't *directly* involved in the conspiracy at all. He might have  been the one who stood to benefit from it, or who "bankrolled" them without knowing the details of the operation. Or perhaps he just *suggested* there might be a conspiracy...

> *"You're so cynical! Half the time I don't think your conspirators even exist!"*

Comment: +1 I take your key point to be that a co-conspirator is another conspirator involved in *the same conspiracy*. Multiple conspirators to an act are simply referred to as conspirators *to that act*. Multiple unrelated conspirators are simply called conspirators (leaving their co-conspirators unidentified, perhaps).

Comment: @Jim: It's not just that co-conspirators are involved in *the same*  conspiracy. Crucial to the usage is that *one of them is already identified within the current context*. That's why it's favoured in usages like ***his** co-conspirators*.

Comment: Interesting. In the news it's usually not directed at a conspirator (e.g. [Alleged co-conspirator in pet store fire...](http://www.lasvegassun.com/news/2014/feb/12/alleged-co-conspirator-pet-store-fire-waives-extra/)), but it does emphasize they are being added to an already identified other involved in the undertaking.

Comment: I would be quite likely (depending on context, of course) to understand _your conspirators_ as referring to ‘those who conspire against you’, whereas _your co-conspirators_ unambiguously states that ‘you’ is involved in the conspiracy not as its victim, but as a conspirator.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to say that it isn't redundant.  Two people can be conspirators, but in two different conspiracies.  Co-conspirator tells us that they are conspiring together rather than conspiring with other people.  So it provides us with an additional piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

Come to think of it, it might be superfluous in some cases.

However the word "co" might carry an important meeting in some other cases. The prefix "co", though it denotes equality in some usage (co-owner, co-teacher) might also suggest that one has a secondary or less important role (Think pilot, co-pilot). So we might use "co-conspirator" to call someone who had a minor role in a conspiracy, although it's true that we also use this term to describe people who had equal participation in the conspiracy. In this instance, it does appear to be redundant--but something that's considered reputable usage.

So I wouldn't say that "co" in "co-conspirator" is entirely useless.

Comment: I don't think *co-conspirator* is really the same as *co-pilot, co-driver*. Very often in those usages the "main man" will still be called the *pilot, driver*. With *co-conspirators*, they're normally all considered ***equal*** within the conspiracy. You wouldn't normally expect a reference to *a conspirator* (the main one) ***and*** his *co-conspirators* (under his command), in the same sentence.